# Trying to Fetch data from mongoDB using mongoose without using model and schema and did not get printed data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://choudharykamal620:<password>@cluster0.i9h833n.mongodb.net/gofoodmern?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

const mongoDB = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('connected to MongoDB');
            const fetched_data = mongoose.connection.db.collection("food_items");
            console.log("1")
            fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
                console.log("2");
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else console.log(data);
                 console.log("3");
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB: ', error);
        })
        console.log("4");
    };
    
    module.exports = mongoDB;
```

i have written my password in place of password in my real code.

I have written this function to fetch data from mongoDB using mongoose but didn't get desired output. mongoose is got connected with mongoDB

```
received output:
connected to MongoDB
1
4



 Expected output:
    connected to MongoDB
    1
    2
    documents fetched
    3
    4
```

Comment: How do you select the desired database?

Comment: i have edited code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');

        let fetched_data = mongoose.connection.db.collection("food_items");
        let data = await fetched_data.find({}).toArray(); // Use await here to wait for the data

        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB: ', error);
    }
};
```

this code works !!